Is it best practice to check the token balance when withdrawing ERC20 tokens from a contract?
A smart contract which stores ERC20 tokens.
When withdrawing an amount from the contract I found examples of checking the token balance before making the transfer:
IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
uint256 contractBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
require(contractBalance >= amount, "Insufficient token balance in contract");

In the ERC20 implementation itself there is a check for the token balance in _update:
uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
if (fromBalance < value) {
  revert ERC20InsufficientBalance(from, fromBalance, value);
}

As I understand it if the contract happens to have less of the token balance than the amount, the transaction would revert with the error message of the ERC20 standard anyway.
Isn't it wasteful to check for the balance twice?

It's not recommended. The token contract already has a check to make sure the sender has enough balance for a transfer. This check adds completely unnecessary gas to the transaction.
To answer what @shadow said regarding the transfer function consuming large amounts of gas before failing: while true, this should be completely disregarded. Before sending the transaction, wallets and dapps simulate first whether the transaction is going to revert before sending, so NO gas is used.
You should optimize for the happy path and reduce gas cost for all successful transfers. It's a mistake and poor design if a transaction is ever sent to be executed when the contract doesn't have enough balance.

There is no way to tell beforehand if a transaction will fail or not if a contract has approved another address to spend it's tokens . Lets say the contract has  300 token balance and it has approved X address to spend 200 tokens . Now, you and X make a transaction at the same block. If X's transaction gets ordered first the contract only has 100 tokens while you are attempting to withdraw 300, leading it down to the path that I mentioned . No simulation can tell whether X's transaction will be ordered before or after you as tx ordering is in hands of the validators.

Not true, and again is typically a mistake and poor design. The scenario you're describing is very specific and still can be simulated before inclusion.
Scenario:

multiple users have access to transfer the tokens from the same contract (strange for token transfers here)
the traffic on the contract is enough where these collisions happen often enough to justify the saved gas on failures compared to the cumulate gas saved for every successful tx

Solution:

validators can simulate the tx given previous txs in the block. Many such services (see flashbots). This is the happy path.


You are right , the happy path concept makes more sense instead of designing for a failure case . Its better for one user to lose all his gas rather than for everyone else to pay more gas  .
I do think the approve assumption is fair since op mentioned it's interacting with ERC20 tokens . Without more context it's pointless to discuss this point.
